# Configuring NFSv4 anonymous ownership mapping (idmapd.conf) per subtree or mount?

Tags: linux, nfs4

The NFSv4 idmap approach allows a great deal of flexibility in terms of how users and accounts are mapped between the NFS server and the local system -- but with this comes significant configuration complexity. If trying to build a turnkey solution that works with any site-local NFS server, this can be particularly unfortunate.

Is there a reasonable mechanism for a Linux NFSv4 client to available to mount an NFS server with a different user account mapped to the anonymous user for different subtrees, *or* to have different mounts off the same server with different idmaps assigned?

That is to say:

```
/mnt/server-a/foo ## in this subtree, unknown owners are mapped to the local account "foo"
/mnt/server-a/bar ## in this subtree, unknown owners are mapped to the local account "bar"
```

I'm even considering approaches such as loopback fuse-based servers -- though the performance impact would make this quite unfortunate.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can do it on the server itself. Here is an example of export file:

```
/foo client(rw,fsid=0,all_squash,anonuid=123,anongid=123)
/bar client(rw,fsid=1,all_squash,anonuid=567,anongid=567)
```

where 123 and 567 are uid/gid of users foo and bar. The different fsids are there to avoid merging of mounts on the client side.

Comment: Unfortunately, the point here is to be server-agnostic -- to provide an client that can be deployed against any NFSv4 server with a minimum of local configuration.